# Why is the polynomial $f(x)=x^3+x^2+x+1$ monotonic?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I have to argue why the polynomial $f(x)=x^3+x^2+x+1$ has a reverse function $f^{-1}$ which is defined in on the whole of $\mathbb R$. I'm certain the argument would simply be that because $f(x)$ is monotonic on $\mathbb R$ it is also injective on $\mathbb R$. However I can not argue why $f(x)$ would be monotonic. A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

English is not my first language, please do say if my terminology is off.

Comment: I added the calculus tag. If it is not meant to be solved with calculus (derivatives etc.) I'll edit back! :)

Comment: the tag is absolutely justified

Comment: is it possible to accredit more than one answer?

Comment: You can upvote all relevant, and accept (and also upvote) the one that suits you best

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

$f'(x)=3x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2+2x^2>0$

Comment: I just recently enrolled in an engineering problem, after a couple of years out of school. because er completely forgot that the first thing one ever does when looking at monotony is find the derivative. thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Sebastian: You are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

I think you could consider the derivative and show it is always positive on $\mathbb{R}$, using the fact that it (the derivative) has no real roots, if calculus is acceptable for this problem.

Comment: This is also a good answer finding that the discriminant is less than 0 for the derivative.

Answer (score 2):

Without calculus, you could look at $f(y)-f(x)=(y-x)(x^2+xy+y^2+x+y+1)$, and show that the right-hand side is positive whenever $y>x$.

Comment: i had not considered solving this problem without calculus, interesting.

Comment: If you multiply both sides by $2$ the desired conclusion becomes clear, since $2(x^2+xy+y^2+x+y+1)=(x+y)^2+(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2$.